# dynamic textfield when select box changes

Tags: javascript, html, textfield

I have been looking pretty hard for an answer to this and have attacked it from my code and from basic browser set up.  What I am trying to do is have a text field change based on what a select box is set to.  What I have put together thus far does exactly what I want it to do in all browsers but Explorer.  Is there anything further I need to declare to achieve this or is there another method that would be better for my end goal?

This is what i have at the moment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeusf() 
{
    document.getElementById("usf").setAttribute("value",optionsusf.value); 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" value="" name="usf" id="usf"/>

<select id="optionsusf" name="optionsusf" onchange="changeusf()">
   <option value="--------------------">Select One</option>
   <option value="0.00">No Tax</option>
   <option value="0.18">18% Tax</option>
   <option value="0.07">7% Tax</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<select id="optionsusf" name="optionsusf" onchange="changeusf(this.value);">
<option value="--------------------">Select One</option>
<option value="0.00">No Tax</option>
<option value="0.18">18% Tax</option>
<option value="0.07">7% Tax</option>
</select>

function changeusf(val) 
{
    document.getElementById("usf").value = val; 
}
```

In this we are using simple `JavaScript` to pass the value `onchange` of `select box` to the function and in that function we are just receiving the value and putting it in `textbox`. So we are not using anything which creates any problem in any `browser`.

Comment: This works.  Could you provide me with a reason?  kinda new to javascript and would like to know the why.  Thank you

Comment: I just added explanation to the answer.

Comment: Done. did forget, glad I was looking at it again for you to get credit.

Answer (score 1):

You should be just doing:

`document.getElementById("usf").value = document.getElementById("optionsusf").value;`

instead of using `setAttribute`

Comment: I did start off with that and had the same outcome.  On all browsers that do what I want both work equally as well.  What I have at the moment is me running things to try but I will change it back.

Answer (score 0):

1.add the following jquery code in `changeusf` function 
`$("#usf").val($("#optionsusf option:selected").text())`
Remember to include jquery .